# Sorting an array of songs by Album, when Album info available

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, mpmediaquery

I'm populating an array with songs that match a specific criteria.

```
  NSArray *songs = [[[MPMediaQuery alloc] init] items];
  NSMutableArray *filteredSongs;
  for (int i=0; i<[songs count]; i++) {
       // filter logic here: if songs[i] match the criteria, push it filteredSongs array

  }
```

Now I'd like to sort that array by `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle`, but avoiding problems if the Album info of the user's mp3 is missing.
(I'm trying to find a workaround for the problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559931/no-songs-detected-on-ipad))

Comment: Hmm, so what's the problem? If the album info is missing, just remove those songs from the array before you sort.

Comment: mmmm no, i need to show them all, sorting them by album if the info exists

Comment: I didn't say don't show them all. I said sort without the ones that lack the album info. Then put those ones back in. I have no idea where you think they go, or how you think they should be ordered; you did not specify your input / desired output. All I'm saying is that this is trivial.

Comment: looks like the answer by @Jared it's working :)

Comment: If it's working, can you please select it as the answer so people searching later on can find it easier.

Comment: of course @Jared , today I'll finish all the tests to confirm it and I'll mark it as ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [NSComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) to sort by album title.  This should handle nil albumTitle values and push them to the back.

```
[songs sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
return [[obj2 albumTitle] compare:[obj1 albumTitle]];
}];
```